# Native UI Component throws Invariant Violation: tried to register two views with the same name FridgeCameraView

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-native-ui-component

Trying to learn React Native custom Native UI Components.

```
// FridgeCameraViewManager.swift

import UIKit

@objc(FridgeCameraViewManager)
class FridgeCameraViewManager: RCTViewManager {

  override func view() -> UIView! {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Swift Component"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    return label
  }

  @objc static override func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return false
  }
}
```

.

```
// FridgeCameraViewManager.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "React/RCTViewManager.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(FridgeCameraViewManager, RCTViewManager)


@end
```

.

```
// FridgeCameraView.js

import {requireNativeComponent} from 'react-native';
const FridgeCameraView = requireNativeComponent('FridgeCameraView', null);
export default FridgeCameraView;
```

When I try to use FridgeCameraView component somewhere in App.js, it works only If I build & run the project using Xcode. Otherwise, using hot reload when changing something, I get "Invariant Violation: tried to register two views with the same name FridgeCameraView".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, the error went away when I installed `react-router-native`. I think there was a package conflict or something that I was missing. Hopefully, this will be a fix for the ones who encounter this error in the future. I'm still waiting for explanations if somebody knows what's behind this weird error.

Answer (score 0):

*(Not a solution, but still want to contribute)*

**TL;DR**:

1. Just press `R` in terminal to refresh app
2. Auto hot-reload will register `FridgeCameraView` twice, reason unknown

For those of you who are wondering what's going on, we're learning the React Native - iOS Native Component and following the tutorial:

[Swift in React Native - The Ultimate Guide Part 1: Modules](https://teabreak.e-spres-oh.com/swift-in-react-native-the-ultimate-guide-part-1-modules-9bb8d054db03)

[Swift in React Native - The Ultimate Guide Part 2: UI Components](https://teabreak.e-spres-oh.com/swift-in-react-native-the-ultimate-guide-part-2-ui-components-907767123d9e)

And this is part 2 UI Components that went wrong. As React / React Native are changing fast, this scared resource on native component soon became outdated.

I accidentally need to reinstall my macOS & node_module, no luck in getting rid of the error. Installing another package doesn't solve the issue either.

I suspect that during React Native bridging in Swift -> Objective C -> React-JS, React Native will register our customized module `FridgeCameraView` twice; but will need expect in Objective C to dig deeper on this issue. Any contribution is welcomed!

Comment: I have absolutely the same issue and can not find any solution for this. Did you figure it out?

Comment: This article works https://www.admios.com/blog/react-native-ui-native-components-in-swift-and-java